# WEBOTS: Two-wheeled platform and stabilization setting

Tags: webots

I created a two-wheeled platform that I want to stabilize. But I do not understand through which device or through the program code to do this.

I expect the platform to be upright.

Comment: it looks like a platform https://imgur.com/rQrnpqe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need to add a Gyro (https://www.cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/gyro) and an Inertial Unit (https://cyberbotics.com/doc/reference/inertialunit) to know the angle of the robot and the rotation speed.

You can also find an example of this (not exactly similar as it use a position sensor to know the angle of another Solid node) here:
https://robotbenchmark.net/benchmark/inverted_pendulum/